# How to set table width with phpword?

Tags: php, phpword

Documentation says that table width can be set in addTable, but I don't understand how to make it work. Also I need to set 100% width
I tried:

```
$table = $section->addTable(array(
  'width' => 100
));
$table = $section->addTable(array(
  'width' => '100'
));
$table = $section->addTable(array(
  'width' => '100%'
));
```

But nothing seems to work. What should I write to make it work?

Comment: Please reject the last edit, I clicked the on wrong review button by mistake.

Answer (score 6):

try this...

$table = $section->addTable(array('unit' => \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Table::WIDTH_PERCENT, 'width' => 100 * 50));

Comment: Don't know why 100*50 but is working to set 100% width. Anyone knows why?

Comment: @EricLagarda according to comments in PHPWord code, WIDTH_PERCENT does not refer to the percent but to the fiftieth of percent. See for yourself: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/aca10785cf68dc95d7f6fac4fe854979fef3f8db/src/PhpWord/Style/Table.php#L34

Comment: Showing Table::WIDTH_PERCENT is not defined.

Answer (score -1):

When you look on the documentation (https://www.phpdocx.com/api-documentation/word-content/add-table-Word-document-with-PHP) I believe you are using it wrong.

`$docx->addTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);` your options parameter should come after table values.

Something like this?

```
require_once 'classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();

$valuesTable = array(
    array(
        11,12,13,14
    ),
    array(
        21,22,23,24
    ),
    array(
        31,32,33,34
    ),
);

$paramsTable = array(
  'width' => 100, // not sure if width 100 is valid parameter though check the documentation
);

$docx = $section->addTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);
```

Comment: this returns empty document

Comment: Yes. You have to inicialize the object `$docx = new CreateDocx();` the you have to add the table `$docx = $section->addTable($valuesTable, $paramsTable);` and finally return the document `$docx->createDocx('example_addTable_1');`. I hope this will help. :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I work with phpWord library, not with phpdocx:)